# Thread error in my android application

Tags: android, orientation, crash-reports

Whenever I change the orientation, there is an error with the thread and my application closes unexpectedly.

Here is the error code

```
03-23 11:25:40.021: W/dalvikvm(27571): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cecae0)
03-23 11:25:40.021: E/AndroidRuntime(27571): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11869
03-23 11:25:40.021: E/AndroidRuntime(27571): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 11:25:40.021: E/AndroidRuntime(27571): at my.app.Methods$1.run(Methods.java:34)
```

Here is the code for the thread :

```
SettingsPreferences mSettingsPreferences = new SettingsPreferences(mContext);
public void loadStatistic (final ProgressBar progBar, final SettingsPreferences settPref, final String max, final String progress, final int defaultValue) {
        Thread t = new Thread () {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(100);
                    progBar.setMax(settPref.getInt(max, defaultValue));
                    progBar.setProgress(settPref.getInt(progress, defaultValue));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: `progBar` is probably null. Also you are updating ui from a thread which is wrong. Update ui on th ui thread. When orientation changes activity is destroyed and re-created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are trying to acccess the UI on a seperate thread. You will need to use an `AsyncTask` thread which will enable you to periodically access the UI thread.

For example:

```
private class ExampleThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         while(!isCancelled()) { // Keep going until cancelled
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(100); // Delay 100 milliseconds
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 Thread.interrupted();
             }
             publishProgress(); // Run onProgressUpdate() method
             if(isCancelled()) break; // Escape early if cancel() is called
         }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... params) {
        // Here you can access the UI thread
        progBar.setMax(settPref.getInt(max, defaultValue));
        progBar.setProgress(settPref.getInt(progress, defaultValue));
    }
}
```

To start the thread:

```
ExampleThread thread = new ExampleThread();
thread.execute();
```

To stop the thread:

```
thread.cancel();
```

More information and examples with AsyncTask can be found on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example).

Comment: It works only when the app is started, it show me the exact progress bar status(1/3 in this case) but when I rotate, It shows only a small gap on the progress bar.

Comment: So the problem is solved, but now the activity state is not restored on orientation change? See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

You must update all of your UI elements on the main or UI thread. I would recommend creating an `AsyncTask` subclass and then implementing `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` to start and stop the progress bar or to measure times. Then do all of your UI things on `runOnUiThread` .
runOnUiThread takes a Runnable as an argument so you can do everything your heart desires